# How to generate confidence bands for $\hat{Y}$

Tags: confidence-interval, linear-model, standard-deviation, prediction-interval

Suppose I run a linear regression model. I am interested in generating prediction intervals. The predicted values are easy to compute, but how can I compute the standard deviations for each of the $\hat{Y}$s?

In R, I use the `predict.lm` function and use the `interval='prediction'` argument. I wouldsubtract the highest bound of the CI to the actual number and divide by 1.96 for 95% CI but I would like to get it directly to be sure.

I tried se.fit = TRUE and stuff like that but did not work.

Comment: What confidence interval are you trying to compute? One for regression coefficients? One for fitted values? What do you mean by "Series of SD[s]"?

Comment: Thanks.
Yes sorry, I want the Prediction Interval of fitted values.
Well, I thought that the interval could be computed by just adding 1.96*Residual standard error.
But when you get the interval with the option interval = "prediction", the wideness is not constant. So I guess the standard error is a function of the fitted value. I would like to get those values

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544090/predict-lm-in-r-how-to-get-confidence-intervals-right

Comment: Also use `, interval = 'prediction'` in `predict.lm`

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did not find it before.
But this is exactly ny problem. In your post, prediction interval wideness is constant and mine is not when I use interval = 'prediction' in predict.lm, why?

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have said `, interval = 'confidence'`. Read the post more carefully (it's not mine, for instance). At any rate, the confidence bands *do actually change* for both confidence/prediction intervals for the $\hat{y}$s, it's just that when prediction is used, you add the variability of an individual observation which is overwhelming compared to the variability of the confidence band, so you just can't see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam ! But do you know how I can get the standard deviation used to compute those intervals in R?

Comment: My new answer should address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By fitting an lm object you obtain all the necessary components to do this. Mathematically you have estimates:

$$\hat{\beta} = \left( \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} \right) ^{-1} \left( \mathbf{X}^T y \right) $$

and and estimate:

$$\mbox{vcov}\left(\hat{\beta} \right) = \hat{\sigma}^2 \left( \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} \right) ^{-1}  $$

the beta-hats are obtained by calling `coef` to the `lm` object and the variance estimate, `vcov` to the `lm` object.

Mathematically, for any $\mathbf{X}_{pred}$ observation you wish to predict the fitting $\hat{Y} = E \left[ Y | \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{X}_{pred} \right]$ then since the $\hat{Y}$ is given by: $\mathbf{X}_{pred}^T \hat{\beta}$ it is a simple mathematical manipulation to find that:

$$\mbox{var} \left( \hat{Y} \right) = \mathbf{X}_{pred}^T  \mbox{vcov}\left(\hat{\beta} \right) \mathbf{X}_{pred} = \hat{\sigma}^2 \mathbf{X}_{pred}^T \left( \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} \right) ^{-1} \mathbf{X}_{pred} $$

It is a simple rule of quadratic forms that the farther $\mathbf{X}_{pred}$ is from the sample mean for each covariate (in a Euclidean sense), the greater $\left( \mathbf{X}_{pred}^T\mathbf{X}_{pred} \right)$ will be and, hence, the greater the variance of $\hat{Y}$.

Simply, the variance only differs as a function of the cross product of your predicted $X$. An illustrating example in R since you seem to be interested in both the theoretical and computational aspects...

```
x <- 1:100
y <- rnorm(100, x, 100)
plot(x, y)
f <- lm(y ~ x)
X <- model.matrix(f)
pred.se <- apply(X, 1, function(Xrow) t(Xrow) %*% vcov(f) %*% Xrow)
lines(1:100, 1:100 + 1.96*sqrt(pred.se))
lines(1:100, 1:100 - 1.96*sqrt(pred.se))
## "conf band is for uncertainty in predicted ys, should be substantially 
## tighter than observed vales
```

[image]

Comment: This is the interval for predictions of the mean response; for the intervals of predictions of the observed response, you should add \sigma^2 to above.  For details, see section 3.5, "Confidence intervals for predictions" in J. J. Faraway, "Practical Regression and Anova using R". [https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf]

Comment: As for better the R code, it's preferable to reuse the predict function, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12544642/2103990

Answer (score -2):

we have
$$
\hat{\beta}\pm t_{\alpha/2,n-2} \sqrt{\frac{MSE}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}
$$
then

```
  l=lm(y~x)
  MSE=mean ( (l$residuals)^2) 
      SSX=sum ( (x-mean(x))^2 )
      U= l$coefficients + qt(1-alpha/2,n-2) * sqrt(MSE/SSX)
  L= l$coefficients - qt(1-alpha/2,n-2) * sqrt(MSE/SSX)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but my point is that with this formula, the widness of the interval is constant. However when I call predict(..., interval = "prediction") the given interval is not...

Comment: Just in case it matters, it is a multiple linear regression.
I know it should change the student law quantile, etc. but it does not answer to my problem of unconstant interval confident wideness right?

Comment: @LoïcMongellaz See AdamO's comment. You seem to be confusing two kinds of intervals: the one Hamed gives is for the *coefficients* of the regression. The one you seem to want is for the *fitted values*. AdamO's link provides exactly that.

Comment: this formula works for coefficients not response. I guess you are looking for prediction interval. Is that right?

Comment: This does not answer the questuon.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I see thanks. this question was not quite clear. anyway thanks.

Comment: Yes Hamed you are right, I want the prediction interval of fitted values not parameters.
To me, the wideness of the interval should remain constant whatever is the fitted value, but it is not when you call predict.lm(..., interval = "prediction").
In the link of  AdamO, confindence interval is not constant but prediction is, which does not happen for me, why ?
Thanks.